# Which license should I use

Tags: licensing, open-source-definition, google-play

I want to share my android project on GitHub, allow everyone contribute to it but I don't want them to upload the project to play store without changing anything. Because I will be doing it. Why I want this is I want to be the official distributor of it, otherwise there would be a ton of the same app in store.

There is no problem in uploading it after changing it though. They can distribute their own version as long as it is different and open-sourced.

I am not sure if this is even against the definition of open source but can there be a license that says what I want?

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/10290/458) to see the other side of the coin.  But the upshot is that no free software licence will prevent people doing what you want; the free software way to achieve your aim is to make your version the best-supported, and the most responsively and rapidly updated, packaged version of this application.

Comment: @MadHatter I think that depends a bit on what the OP means by "without changing it"; if a change of name is OK then that probably can be open source.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Well, changing the name is changing something I guess. I wish they suggested that name to my repository and we moved on with it but anyways they can leave the repository and make their own version with a new name. But can I force anyone making their own version to share the source code openly to everyone? Can some LICENSE document in a GitHub repository force someone to do something? Would Google Play Store care about me when I say 'they don't share the source code'?

Comment: @PhilipKendall the way to do that is not with a licence, but with a trademark.